# sign in form is working fine on localhost but not on host

Tags: php, localhost, prepared-statement, host

this sign in process is working fine in my localhost but when i upload it on host and try to test it on live server it fails!
i uploaded my database to server and tried to sign in with a registered user, but when i submitted the form nothing happened!
i use ajax and alert the data returned from server and it just alerted a blank message, no error, no warning, no data echoed!

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id;
$status = 1;

require_once("../scripts/config.php");

$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(email) AS counte FROM users WHERE email=?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $obj = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();
    $counte = $obj->counte;
    $stmt->close();
}

if($counte == 1) // email mojud ast
{
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS countr, id, fname, lname, img FROM users LEFT JOIN userd ON users.id = userd.userid WHERE email=? AND password=?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $obj = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();
    $countr = $obj->countr;
    $id = $obj->id;
    $fname = $obj->fname;
    $lname = $obj->lname;
    $img = $obj->img;
    $stmt->close();
    if($countr == 0)
    {
        echo "incorrect";
    }
    else if($countr == 1)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $id;
        echo $img."*".$fname." ".$lname."*".$id."*";
    }
}
}
else if($counte == 0)
{
echo "notexist";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if($counte == 1) // email mojud ast
{
   }
```

try this

```
if($counte > 0) 
{
   }
```

this is what I use on my login module
if ever you want to consider using PDO here is my code feel free to use it as reference

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=". DB_host .";dbname=db", DB_username , DB_password);



      $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

      //checking if  valid
      $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:var1 AND password=:var2 ";
      $stmt=$con2->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':var1',$var1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':var2',$var2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();

       if($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){



      }
```

Comment: as i said it works fine on my localhost! i think the problem is with prepared statement, cause i checked other queries and i found out that neither they work!

Comment: have you checked your php.ini then?

Comment: i don't know how to access it from c-panel!